# Basis properties of finite-dimensional normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional normed space and let $\left\lbrace e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots, e_{n}\right\rbrace$ be a basis in $E$. Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left\| e_{k}\right\|\le \text{dim} (E)$ $?$

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Consider the vectors:
$$e_1 = (1,0,1)$$
$$e_2 = (1,1,0)$$
$$e_3 = (0,0,1)$$
These form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. But then:
$$\left|\left|e_1 \right|\right| = \sqrt{2}$$
$$\left|\left|e_2\right|\right| = \sqrt{2}$$
$$\left|\left|e_3\right|\right| = 1$$
where I am using the usual Euclidean norm. So, you see that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3} \left|\left|e_k \right|\right| = 2\sqrt{2}+1 > 3 = \text{dim}(\mathbb{R}^3)$$

I am interested in knowing what would suggest that this inequality holds?

Answer (score 0):

Pick any basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $E$, and define a new basis $\{e_1',\dots,e_n'\}$ by letting

$$e_j'=\frac{\dim(E)+1}{\lVert e_j\rVert}e_j.$$

Then

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \lVert e_j'\rVert=n(\dim(E)+1)>\dim(E),$$

proving that we can turn **any** basis into a counterexample (with the exception of when $\dim(E)=0$). Why would you assume it to be true?